# Is it possible to change the color component of a style?

Tags: css

Say I have a class as follows:

```
.X {
   border:1px solid red;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Is it possible to change, using script, the color of `border` and or `background-color` of class `X` without affecting all other properties?

Comment: Yes by jQuery/JavaScript, or some CSS that behave in a dynamic fashion. By other properties do you mean the other properties of other elements that have class `.X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said it is possible to change the style definition, but do you really want to do that? I think you can achieve the same result just by adding another class

```
$('.X').addClass('blue');
```

and add this to you styles:

```
.X.blue {background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can use a little JavaScript.

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".X");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
    myElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: It should be myElements[i].style.backgroundColor instead of myElements[i].style.background-color

Comment: Changing _color_ of border: `myElements[i].style.borderColor = "darkgreen";` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indeed change the css properties of an element using Javascript or jQuery as suited.

**Javascript way**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("X")[0].style.border = "1px solid blue";
```

Read more about the [HTMLElement.style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

**jQuery way**

```
$(".X").css("border", "1px solid blue");
```

Read more about the [jQuery.css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the use case

```js
// All elements with the class X
const elX = document.querySelectorAll('.X');
elX.forEach(i => i.setAttribute("style", "color: green; border:solid tomato"));

// First element with the class Y
const elY = document.querySelector('.Y');
// All at once
// elY.setAttribute("style", "color: tomato; border:solid tomato");

// Or you can set the styles individually
elY.style.color = "tomato";
elY.style.border = "solid tomato";
```

```html
<div class="X">
  <h1>Yo!</h1>
</div>

<div class="X">
  <h1>Yo!</h1>
</div>

<div class="Y">
  <h1>Yo!</h1>
</div>
<div class="Y">
  <h1>Yo!</h1>
</div>
```